# Should I run tests during the docker build?

Tags: python, docker, testing, python-poetry

I have a Dockerfile like this:

```
FROM python:3.9

WORKDIR /app

RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y

RUN curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/python-poetry/poetry/master/install-poetry.py | python -

ENV PATH /root/.local/bin:$PATH

COPY pyproject.toml poetry.lock Makefile ./

COPY src ./src

COPY tests ./tests

RUN poetry install && poetry run pytest && make clean

CMD ["bash"]
```

As you can see that tests will be run during the build. It could slow down the build little bit, but will ensure that my code runs in the Docker container.

If tests pass in my local machine, does not mean that they will also pass in the docker container.

Suppose I add a feature in my code that uses chromedriver or ffmpeg binaries, that is present in my system, so tests will pass in my system.

But, suppose I forget to install those dependencies in the Dockerfile, then the docker build will fail (as tests are running during the build)

What is the standard way of doing what i am trying to do ?

Is my Dockerfile good ? or should i do something differently ?

Comment: Images are built layer by layer, and in a Dockerfile, each instruction creates a layer in the resulting image. As per my understanding, executing test each time invalidates the cache due to which subsequent layers won’t be loaded from the cache and hence you will not be able to fully utilize the caching concept which speeds up subsequent build.

Comment: thank you for this insight. i am new to docker, and I was not aware of this.

Comment: No issues, Please go through the following links for the docker file best practices: (!) https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/ (2) For Python : https://pythonspeed.com/articles/docker-caching-model/

Comment: The issue is that Docker is not meant for running tests. I believe Tests should be part of your pipeline. You need a test environment that is identical to the container environment where you will run the code for production (use the same image i.e. ). It is fine to run tests on the image after deployment. I wouldn't include them as part of the dockerfile. Apply tests to that environment and when they pass tag the build. Then you know build X.X.X passed the tests. When you have this mechanism in place, you can just use it in the "test phase" of your pipeline.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run pytest on image construction makes no sense to me. However, what you can do is run tests after the image is completed. In your pipeline you should have something like this:

1. Test your python package locally
2. Build wheel with poetry
3. Build docker image with your python package
4. Run your docker image to test if it works (running pytests for example)
5. Publish your tested image to container registry

Comment: how will i do the point 4 ? i mean i should copy the tests directory into the image ? (while defining Dockerfile)

and run `docker run pyproject poetry run pytest`

Comment: That is an option, but you will be doing unit tests. In point 4 you need to do integrity tests, you perhaps you should invoke public methods to see that execution is done correctly.

Answer (score 7):

If you use multiple stages, you can run `docker build` and avoid running the tests, and if you want to run the tests afterwards, running `docker build --target test` would then run the tests on what was previously built. This approach is explained on the [docker official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/language/java/run-tests/#multi-stage-dockerfile-for-testing).

This way not only we avoid running the build twice due to the Docker caching mechanism, we also can avoid having the test code being shipped in the image.

A possible use case of this implementation when doing CI/CD is to run the two commands when developing locally and in the CI; and not run the tests command in the CD, because the code being deployed will already be tested.